# .NET 4 equivalent of Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-ctp

In .NET 4, is there any functional equivalent to .NET 4.5's [System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

The goal is to wrap up multiple async tasks into a single one that is completed when all of its constituent tasks are done.

Comment: @L.B `Parallel.Invoke` doesn't operate on `Task`s, it operates on `Action`s.

Comment: @MonroeThomas, So Is it forbidden to use Actions? And as you can see I posted as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: @L.B I would venture that Actions are not appropriate here because the OP has explicitly stated `async tasks`, and has reinforced that by specifying that he wants the signature and behaviour of `Task.WhenAll`, which only accepts `IEnumerable<Task>`.   `Parallel.Invoke` does not return a `Task`, which the OP is also looking for.

Comment: Can you just use the async targeting pack?  Not sure if it contains that or not off-hand

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the closest thing built-in in .Net 4.0 is [`ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321258). You can make the `continuationAction` a simple `tasks => tasks` and use the returned `Task`.

For performance reasons, you might want to use it with `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.

Comment: @MonroeThomas, thanks for that excellent link - the Task.Factory extensions are very handy, and the rest of the parallel programming examples look fascinating.

Answer (score 27):

In .NET Framework 4.0 WhenAll and WhenAny can be used with installed [AsyncCTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) in case of Visual Studio 2010 or [Async Targeting Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576) in case of Visual Studio 2012.

The WhenAll and WhenAny methods are then offered on the TaskEx type.

Comment: This should be the top answer, IMO.

Comment: i can't found WhenAll eventhough i installed AsyncCTP for VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Try waiting on `Task.WaitAll()` in another Task.  Use the LINQ extension method `ToArray` to convert from `IEnumerable<Task>` to `Task[]`.

```
Task WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  Your answer is better.  Thanks!